# How to decode obfuscated text for NLP problem?

Tags: python, encryption, text, nlp, decode

I have training data as obfuscated text for an NLP classification problem. The data has been obfuscated, however the patterns in them are preserved. I want to decode it. I don't know how. Also, I'm not sure if it needs to be decoded for training the models. Any ideas? Two sample lines from the text are below:

```
    tvletwgzkrqvuhtwamuluhpkskpmpmiwtvuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhqgvipmmvulkriwpmqvtwleuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhqgqvqvtwviezlemvxeuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhpkskvieniwlrvikquhqvmvuhqgpmpmiwletwulenokuhxepmuhtwiwululentvuhtwamuluhvimvuhsktwlemvezskenuhtwtvuhulqvkrezuhamypmvamdfuhulenamguuhraskvipmyptwqvuhtwamuluhxepmuhvimvenulgzenypuhenuhsatvuhvipmdfuhqgletwsklepmuhulqvlemvxeuhtwamuluhxepmuhtwiwululentvuhenuhqvmvuhpmpmiwletwulenok

    qvmvuhskleenmvviengzxyuhqvmvamguuhrakrpmsauhulyptwulpmlegzuhskigbhbhkrpmsauhulyptwulpmlegzuhskigbhbhpmfquhraskiwlepmdfuhtwamuluhiwiwenuhlepmxeuhskentwamuhlekrpmsauhxepmuhlemvenamuhenuhullekramuhulviskiwkrpmdfuhiguhratwezuhxepmuhskmvenlexeenuhtwtvuhulvipmskuhqgsapmtvuhsaqjuhraletwskvikriwtvuhletwulxeenuhletwskvikriwtvuhtwskenezuhtwamuhskvienuhezmvamuhvipmgzkruhqvendfuhtwsatwuhqvvienezuhskiwpmuhtwamuluhulkrtv
```

Comment: Letter frequencies?

Comment: care to be more elaborate?

Comment: any ideas yet ?